# Discrete event simulator for asymmetric bandwidth network simulation

Tags: network-programming, simulation, simpy

I am wondering if there exists any discrete event simulator that can simulate a tcp/ip network with asymmetric links. I'm trying to test extreme asymmetries and see how the network performs. [Here](https://github.com/WalkerMills/network_simulator) is a repo for a simpy library that I've found for a great tcp simulator however, the links are symmetric. Simpy is preferred but if there is anything else please let me know. I'm trying to see if there's anything else out there that I might have missed before I try to embark on creating my own network simulator in simpy.

Any help is welcome

Thank you

Comment: can you contrive a small async example to model?

Comment: the 4 discrete event simulation packages I can think of are all single threaded which greatly simplifies event scheduling.  But you can still model async processes.  I have done it.  Technically, all the vehicles in a transportation model or agents in a agent base mode are all async processes.  Can you be a bit more specific on what aspect you having difficulty with?

Comment: @Michael I was specifically trying to see if there are any other libraries that someone else could have made that simulate a tcp/ip network but I hadn't thought of using vehicle transportation models to simulate the connection and that would allow for a async link, do you have any recommendations for where to start?

Comment: no, sorry,  I have been able to build what I need fairly quickly